# C# LINQ How to efficiently deal with a null return?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

So when I'm writing C# linq statements I often would like to do something like this:

```
string name = database.table.Where(t=>t.Field1 == row.Field1 && t.Field2 == row.Field).Select(b=> b.Name).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

However if the statement above doesn't return anything then it errors because you can't use .FirstOrDefault() on a null value.

So what I usually end up doing instead is something like below:

```
var listOfNames = database.table.Where(t=>t.Field1 == row.Field1 && t.Field2 == row.Field).Select(b=> b.Name).ToList();
  
if(listOfNames.Count() > 0 ){
  string name =  listOfNames.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
}
```

The code above just seems really verbose and I have to imagine there is a much cleaner way of doing this while dealing with a potential null return value.

Any insight or help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-). e.g. `string name = /* ... */.FirstOrDefault()?.ToString();` -> would set `name` to `null` for an empty sequence, or he result of `ToString()` on the first element otherwise.

Comment: You can use `FirstOrDefault()` on an *empty sequence* though, which is what `.Where` will return. What you cannot do is call `.ToString()` on a `null` value, but in this case it seems unnecessary to do that anyway (`b.Name` is probably already a string). If you are reflexively adding `.ToString()` to things "just in case it isn't" that's probably a bad habit to kick, since non-string values usually need custom processing.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few ways:

1. do not use `ToString()` I guess Name is string/varchar already

```
string name = database.table
  .Where(t=>t.Field1 == row.Field1 && t.Field2 == row.Field)
  .Select(b=> b.Name)
  .FirstOrDefault()
// name now can be null since default(string) is null
```

2. if you need to do `ToString` then you can use C# 6 features – Null-conditional (?.)

```
string name = database.table
  .Where(t=>t.Field1 == row.Field1 && t.Field2 == row.Field)
  .Select(b=> b.Name)
  .FirstOrDefault()?.ToString(); // here ?
// name now can be null
```

3. also consider null-coalescing (??) operator

```
string name = database.table
  .Where(t=>t.Field1 == row.Field1 && t.Field2 == row.Field)
  .Select(b=> b.Name)
  .FirstOrDefault() ?? "some value"
// so if FirstOrDefault returns null then "some value" will be used
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine the `.Where` and `.FirstOrDefault`:

```
string name = database.table
  .FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Field1 == row.Field1 && t.Field2 == row.Field)
  ?.Name;
```